# A PHP Error was encountered CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have been getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered   Severity: Warning Message: strip_tags()
>   expects parameter 1 to be string, array given Filename:
>   inscription/loginform3.php Line Number: 19

Here is the code:

```
echo form_open_multipart('user/register_step_3');

// Loop through the POST variables passed from the previous page
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $value = htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags($value))); 
  echo form_hidden($key, $value);
}
```

And line 19's code:

```
$value = htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags($value)));
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you print_r($value) and paste it here?

Comment: `$value` is an array, it may has another elements such as `$value[0]`

Comment: Have you looked at CodeIgniter's [input class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) and `$this->input->post`?

Comment: @karan ashar what do you mean by that? do i have to add the print_r($value)?

Comment: $value is not a string here.its an array.make it a string.Please show us the value like print_r($_POST);

Comment: Side note: be aware that `strip_tags()` is not a security function. If you're using it as such, you're probably corrupting user input.

Answer (score 0):

please check your form if any input tag given as array
means:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" />
```

if array field is there you need to use one more inner loop eg:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  if(is_array($value)){
    // Inner loop 
    foreach ($value as $k => $v){
       // Code
    }
  }else{
    $value = htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags($value))); 
    echo form_hidden($key, $value);
  }
}
```

oherwise try out this code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $val = htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST[$key]))); 
  echo form_hidden($key, $val);
}
```